# Access serialized Array in php - WORDPRESS POSTMETA

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization

I have a serialized array that I need to access:-

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:750;s:6:"height";i:330;s:4:"file";s:25:"2017/12/Sophrologie-1.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:21:{s:20:"listingpro-blog-grid";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-372x240.jpg";s:5:"width";i:372;s:6:"height";i:240;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:21:"listingpro-blog-grid2";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-372x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:372;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:21:"listingpro-blog-grid3";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-672x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:672;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:23:"listingpro-listing-grid";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-272x231.jpg";s:5:"width";i:272;s:6:"height";i:231;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:26:"listingpro-listing-gallery";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-580x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:580;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:21:"listingpro-list-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-287x190.jpg";s:5:"width";i:287;s:6:"height";i:190;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:23:"listingpro-author-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:23:"Sophrologie-1-63x63.jpg";s:5:"width";i:63;s:6:"height";i:63;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:25:"listingpro-gallery-thumb1";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-458x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:458;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:25:"listingpro-gallery-thumb2";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-360x198.jpg";s:5:"width";i:360;s:6:"height";i:198;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:25:"listingpro-gallery-thumb3";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-263x198.jpg";s:5:"width";i:263;s:6:"height";i:198;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:25:"listingpro-gallery-thumb4";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-653x199.jpg";s:5:"width";i:653;s:6:"height";i:199;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:25:"listingpro-detail_gallery";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-383x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:383;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:33:"listingpro-checkout-listing-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:24:"Sophrologie-1-220x80.jpg";s:5:"width";i:220;s:6:"height";i:80;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:31:"listingpro-review-gallery-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-184x135.jpg";s:5:"width";i:184;s:6:"height";i:135;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:17:"listingpro-thumb4";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-272x300.jpg";s:5:"width";i:272;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:26:"listingpro_location270_400";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-270x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:270;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:26:"listingpro_location570_455";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-570x330.jpg";s:5:"width";i:570;s:6:"height";i:330;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:26:"listingpro_location570_228";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-570x228.jpg";s:5:"width";i:570;s:6:"height";i:228;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:26:"listingpro_location270_197";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-270x197.jpg";s:5:"width";i:270;s:6:"height";i:197;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:22:"listingpro_cats270_213";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-270x213.jpg";s:5:"width";i:270;s:6:"height";i:213;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:22:"Sophrologie-1-1170x400";a:5:{s:4:"file";s:25:"Sophrologie-1-1170x400jpg";s:5:"width";s:4:"1170";s:6:"height";s:3:"400";s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";s:7:"nova-wp";b:1;}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:19:"Maygutyak - Fotolia";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

I want to retrieve the `Sophrologie-1-1170x400jpg` filename from it (at the bottom of the array).

I can't figure out how to retrieve this filename into this array. The clue is that there is a `nova-wp` value in that row.

This array comes from`wp-postmeta` table in an wordpress installation.

If you could bring me to the direction, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: use [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Answer (score 1):

The data you show has been produced through serialization. Use the [unserialize function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in order to bring it back to its original state:

```
$data = unserialize($text);
```

Then, traverse the deserialized data it in order to retrieve the value you are looking for:

```
echo $data["sizes"]["Sophrologie-1-1170x400"]["file"];
// Output: Sophrologie-1-1170x400jpg
```

A working demo can be found [here](https://eval.in/927414).

If you need to scan your data in order to find the correct value, you can use the following code:

```
$data = unserialize($text);

if (array_key_exists("Sophrologie-1-1170x400", $data["sizes"])) {
    echo $data["sizes"]["Sophrologie-1-1170x400"]["file"];
} else {
    echo "File not found!";
}
```

Comment: I don't know about down-vote, but your answer is also correct.+1